# iOS 7 Safari jquery text() is not being rendered

Tags: jquery, css, safari, ios7, rendering

I am using

```
$('.profile-block .first-name').text(profile_user.first_name)
```

to set my text

```
<h2 class="name">
    <span class="first-name"></span>
    <span class="last-name"></span>
</h2>
```

but the text is not being rendered

I am using iOS 7.0, and its Safari app.

When I open my web inspector, and force the element to re-render like changing the font-size, start editing any css, the text will be visible.

I came up with a solution which is putting   in the node

```
<span class="first-name">&nbsp;</span>
```

then the text gets rendered....

Why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

So you can do something quite nasty (I've not found a better way), to force a browser re-flow:

```
var forceReflow = function(el) {
    el = el || document.body;
    el.style.position = 'static';
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.style.position = 'relative';
    }, 0);
}
```

This should fix your issue. Though it's not the best performant to do it on the `body`, so maybe pass in the parent of `.profile-block`

Comment: @buzz I can't explain it